# How does DP-SGD handle the composition problem between layers?

Tags: neural-networks, differential-privacy

The paper '[Deep Learning with Differential Privacy](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.00133.pdf)' proposed DP-SGD and moments accoutant. The authors consider the NN layers separately, which allows they set different $C$ and $\sigma$ for different layers.

But I don't understand how the layer-wise DPs are composed in DP-SGD. It seems the authors didn't handle the problem at all. I think it's necessary to use [Sequential Composition](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs294-171/fa20/readings/pinq.pdf) at least.

My Question: How does DP-SGD handle the composition problem between layers?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.